# Find anywhere in jList items?

Tags: java, listview, find

I can find item in jlist with this code. But I want to find anywhere in item. How can I do this. Thanks a lot. (Sorry my English)

For example: I can find "New or San" but I want to find "York or Diago".

New York
San Diago

```
  jTextField1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            String text = "" + e.getKeyChar();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(jTextField1.getText().substring(0, jTextField1.getText().length() - 1));
            buffer.append(text);
            int index = jList1.getNextMatch(buffer.toString(), 0, Position.Bias.Forward);
            jList1.setSelectedIndex(index);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**getNextMatch** checks if the given string exists at the start position passed as the second param. You can just traverse the jlist to find the index.

```
jTextField1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        String text = "" + e.getKeyChar();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(jTextField1.getText().substring(0, jTextField1.getText().length() - 1));
        buffer.append(text);
        ListModel<String> model = jList1.getModel();
        int index; 
        for(int i = 0; i < model.getSize(); i++) {
            if(model.getElementAt(i).contains(buffer.toString())){
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        jList1.setSelectedIndex(index);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the method available in JList only searches if the items start with a specific prefix.

```
public List<Integer> getMatches(ListModel listModel, String text){
List<Integer> indices = new List<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < listModel.getSize(); i++){
    if(listModel.getElementAt(i).contains(text)){
        indices.add(i);
    }
}
return indices;
```

}

The method above iterates the listmodel and checks if each element contains the text provided and returns the indices of matched items.